# Provisioning Profiles menu item missing from Xcode 5

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile, xcode5

After spending a whole day installing a fresh copy of [Mac OS X v10.8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mountain_Lion) (Mountain Lion), [Xcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode) 5, fixing provisioning profiles, certificates, creating new ones, I finally managed to get my applications running on my iPad again. The problem is that in Xcode 5 I don't have a menu item for Library - Provisioning Profiles, and I don't know what could have happened. I restarted the computer, tried some things, but I really have no idea what I could do. How can I fix this problem?

[image: Xcode 5 organizer]

Comment: Hasn't it all moved to `Preferences > Accounts`?

Comment: I can't access that part either, I get an "Error Fetching Developer Info" - I don't know if that's due to Apple still reconstructing their developer database or my Xcode 5 installation.

Comment: I'd say it was due to parts of Apple Developer still being down.  Nice timing on that one...

Comment: Please note that tags stand alone.  That is, adding the `provisioning` and `profile` tags doesn't mean the same thing as the `provisoning-profile` tag.  Please be sure to select tags with care!

Comment: @kanstrakta Using my own Apple Id in iCloud fixed that issue for me. I was going to try using my own Apple Id in iTunes next if that hadn't worked.

Answer (score 605, accepted):

These settings have now moved to `Preferences > Accounts`:

[image]

Comment: It seems though, that the provisioning profiles it displays are only those that pertain to that Apple ID. What if you have provisioning profiles installed on your Mac that aren't tied into the development teams your Apple ID is a part of?

Comment: @Vexir Sorry, I've no idea.  That's not something I can test.

Comment: That screen doesn't offer a way to remove provisioning profiles which you don't need?

Comment: @ChrisBurt-Brown (Not at my Mac at the moment) but I **don't** believe it does (see the other answer for something that does).

Comment: Does anyone has the option to remove the multiple Provisional profiles in the app ? I don't find any way to remove the PP from the above Pop screen.

Comment: @AjaySharma Did you check hcris's answer?

Comment: @trojanfoe yes, but thats through the third party software.But What about the inbuilt features in Xcode5 itself ? I didn't find any way to delete any of the provisional profile.

Comment: @AjaySharma No, it's an Apple utility.

Comment: @trojanfoe ohh yes .. thats correct. More on a kind of script. Hows about using it with Xcode. I have installed it but no effect. :(

Comment: @AjaySharma Sorry I've no idea.

Comment: @trojanfoe: How do we delete files from there. It seems that no options for delete a file.

Comment: @Akhildas You are asking the same question as Ajay Sharma; see my responses to his questions.

Comment: You don't delete.  Hit the refresh button at the bottom left and it will sync with the Dev Portal.

Comment: +1 for hit the refresh button. Seems like Xcode will also offer to create/download a profile if you're missing one

Comment: Not available in Xcode 6.  The Accounts tab now shows Repositories.  I manually deleted the profile as mentioned in a different answer by John Connor.

Comment: @ScottCarter You should start a question entitled *Provisioning Profiles menu item missing from Xcode 6* (as opposed to Xcode 5) in order to provide help to others.

Comment: @trojanfoe Great suggestion.  Just posted a question at:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26693855/provisioning-profiles-menu-item-missing-from-xcode-6-as-opposed-to-xcode-5

Comment: Deletion: Right click a provisioning file and click show in finder and delete.

Comment: Provisioning profiles are missing now. You can only download them all in one click.

Answer (score 243):

If you like to manually manage your profiles (mostly to clean up):

- Open Windows/Devices in Xcode 6
- Select your device
- Show Provisioning Profiles:
- [image: open provisioning profiles]
- You'll get **+** and **-** buttons to add/remove profiles:
- [image: profiles]

---

*No longer supported* ... you can also download Apple's iPhone Configuration Utility 3.5 for Mac OS X, it still has "Provisioning Profiles" and works with Xcode 5 -- it's now gone from Apples site but you can find an alternative download link in @suda's comment.

Comment: @hcris Looks good. But still there is no way to remove the provisional profile from here too ...

Comment: @Ajay Sharma - not sure what you mean. I can delete everything from there (just press delete).

Comment: @hcris I mean, any way to remove the provisional profile which are in under Library else provisional prof. which are under devices works well as you instructed.

Comment: @Ajay Sharma - yes you can delete them from the library `worksforme`

Comment: where can i find it after i installed it?

Comment: Okay once I install it and run it, how do I update/refresh new provisioning profiles that were created in the provisioning portal? I cannot see a way to import them using the iPhone Configuration Utility.

Comment: It looks like Apple has removed iPhone Configuration Utility 3.5 for Mac OS X from its servers. There is a copy on Softpedia though: http://mac.softpedia.com/get/System-Utilities/iPhone-Configuration-Utility.shtml#download

Comment: The iPhone Configuration Utility was the best way to manage these profiles all in one place. It has been removed by Apple now, and the version on Softpedia won't install on El Capitan.
The replacement app is supposedly the "Apple Configurator", but that doesn't seem to be available at the moment either.

Answer (score 76):

Provisioning files are located in:

```
/Users/${USER}/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/
```

Just remove the out-of-date files.

Comment: why people are upvoting other stuff? This is the best and the simplest answer to follow.

Comment: Also it works if you do not use Xcode with an Apple ID!

Comment: best answer and also the simplest. there should be multiple accepted answers :)

Comment: From the terminal: `open /Users/${USER}/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/`

Answer (score 39):

[Xcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode) 5 lost my Mac Provisioning Profile while the one for iOS was present. **The tips elsewhere helped solve the problem**; this is what I did, because I noticed the lists were too short and did not include *Mac Team Provisioning Profile: **

1. Xcode menu => *Preferences* => *Accounts*
2. Select the Apple ID in the left panel.
3. Click the **View Details** button on the right.
4. In the pop-over that follows **click the round refresh arrow**. The lists will refresh after the download from the Member Center finishes. This can take a few minutes.
5. The provisioning profiles can then be selected in a Mac project under *Build Settings* => *Code Signing* => *Provisioning Profile*.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

> Xcode >> *Preferences* >> *Accounts*

Answer (score 4):

You can add account in the preference -> Accounts setting.

It seems that you already configure xCode4, then I think you can select your
certificates for compiling in project-> Building Setting directly since your
certificates are already in your keychain.

Answer (score 4):

After searching a few times in google, i found [one software for provisioning profiles](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1465).

Install this iPhone configuration utility software and manage your all provisioning profiles in MAC.

Answer (score 3):

Stupid as it may sound but all "Provisioning Profiles" re-appear under "Organizer - Devices" once you connect a real device.

Comment: That's only for that one device. It doesn't show all the profiles available on your Apple account

Answer (score 2):

For me, the refresh in xcode 5 prefs->accounts was doing nothing.  At one point it showed me three profiles so I thought I was one refresh away, but after the next refresh it went back to just one profile, so I abandoned this method.

If anyone gets this far and is still struggling, here's what I did:

1. Close xcode 5
2. Open xcode 4.6.2
3. Go to Window->Organizer->Provisioning Profiles
4. Press Refresh arrow on bottom right

When I did this, everything synced up perfectly. It even told me what it was downloading each step of the way like good software does.  After the sync completed, I closed xcode 4.6.2, re-opened xcode 5 and went to preferences->accounts and voila, all of my profiles are now available in xocde 5.