# Xcode 5 Provisioning Profiles Not Available

Tags: ios, xcode, configuration, code-signing

I cannot access any of the provisioning profiles or code signing identities that I've created in the project settings. It's not that I haven't downloaded the provisioning profiles, or have the correct certificates installed, but there is nothing that appears in the provisioning profile key in the project settings:

[image: Notice there is no drop-down available for Code Signing Identity either]

Again, I have made sure to import the provisioning profiles and certificates correctly. Here's how my account appears in Preferences > Accounts:

[image: All provisioning profiles, including wildcard profile, are on my local machine]

I'm running out of ideas. I've revoked my existing certificates, deleted all provisioning profiles, and recreated everything again.

I also created a dummy project from Apple's included iOS Master-Detail template. That exhibited the same behavior where no code signing identities or provisioning profiles were available from the project build settings.

I'm pretty open to all ideas. Thanks.

**Update**

As I mentioned, the code signing drop downs don't appear either, even though they have been properly created and downloaded through Preferences / Accounts.

[image]

Comment: Can you please share one more screenshot by clicking on iPhone Developer to show the dropdown list? It may happen that you have selected the wrong Certificate, but I really doubt it. It should at least show some profile names. Also try restarting Xcode if you haven't tried that already.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Nothing is wrong. The solution is simple: Go to Editor -> Show values

Xcode will show all the options after this.

Comment: Haha, like all good answers this is simple and makes me feel like an idiot. So great. Thanks so much, Gudus!

Answer (score 2):

Your provisioning profiles doesn't list out in your project setting because, provisioning profile doesn't match with your bundle identifier.

1) Check your `bundle identifier` to list out provisioning profile as like below picture. Because It also lead to this problem.

[image]

2)You may not using the `correct certificates` when building your app. Just Delete your certificates in Provisioning Portal and create new ones and update them in Xcode.

3) From above description, **you didn't correct bundle identifier**. Goto Organizer / Provisioning Profiles / Refresh and allow Xcode to fetch the latest ones. Then provisioning profile will show as like below

Select correct Provisioning profile.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it must be something else.

1) I have created App-ID's for this bundle, and provisioning profiles for my specific App-ID, but that shouldn't really matter. I should at least be able to select the wildcard profile, and that isn't showing in the provisioning profile drop-down.

2) I have deleted my certificates and created new ones already.

3) With Xcode 5, Apple moved the provisioning profiles from Organizer to Preferences / Accounts / View Details... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041267/provisioning-profiles-menu-item-missing-from-xcode-5?rq=1

Comment: 1) Provisioning profile may created with whether wildcard App-Id or Explicit App-Id, But You must give corresponding bundle identifier. Difference between these two, is format ended with (`*`)(*for ex. com.companyName.demos.`*`)* in wildcard and ended specific app id in explicit(*for ex. com.companyName.YourAppIdentifier*).

Comment: 2) You've deleted old certificate right. did you create new provisioning profile and add it with respect to new certificate. that is.(You have created profile- `A` with respect to certificate `X`, Now You have deleted `X`. and create `Y`, right. Did you create provisioning profile `B` with respect to `Y`?

Comment: 3) Is it all provisioning profile visible in `Preference->Account` with respect to new certificate?

Comment: There is a provisioning profile in my account list (the selected item in my Preferences / Accounts screenshot) with the explicit App-ID, but I can't select it in the Build Settings.

Comment: Yes, I have deleted the old certificates and the old profiles associated with those certificates. After deleting both certificates and profiles, I created the certificates and re-created the profiles.

Comment: Yes, all provisioning profiles appear in the Preferences / Accounts pane.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46891/discussion-between-imani-and-daniel-larsen)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing [iPhone configuration utilities](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1465).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, rkmakwana, but it looks like that didn't really change anything. I can see the provisioning profiles in the iPhone Configuration Utility, but I still can't select them in the project build settings in Xcode.

Comment: did you check the bundle identifier. The bundle id should be the same that you have provided in while creating the app id (which you have used to create the profile). Change the bundle id in plist and check again.