# Provisioning Profiles menu item missing from Xcode 6 (as opposed to Xcode 5)

Tags: xcode, xcode6, provisioning-profile

Xcode 6 does not have a menu item to access provisioning profiles.   How can one manage existing provisioning profiles (list, delete, etc)?

For reference purposes, a similar question was asked pertaining to Xcode 5:

[Provisioning Profiles menu item missing from Xcode 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041267/provisioning-profiles-menu-item-missing-from-xcode-5/18075269)

I commented on the selected answer that in Xcode 6 the Accounts tab now shows Repositories.   I was encouraged to start a new question to help others find information relevant to Xcode 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Adding Apple ID**

As Bo A points out, in order to see more than just Repositories, you need to add an Apple ID.

Select Xcode -> Preferences...

On the Accounts tab, click on the + sign in the lower left corner and select Add Apple ID...
Fill out the required information and select Add.

This addresses the part of the question that indicates that the Accounts tab just shows Repositories.

**Listing provisioning profiles**

As Nikos M. points out, you can select an Apple ID and then the View Details... button to see your provisioning profiles (and signing identities).

**Deleting provisioning profile**

Another part of the question was asking about how to delete a provisioning profile (in addition to listing).  It appears that there are two steps to this process:

1. Right click on a provisioning profile (that you listed from above) and select Show in Finder.  You can then move the highlighted item to the trash.
2. Go to the Member Center on developer.apple.com and follow links to the section on Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles.   Find and delete the provisioning profile of interest.

If you only remove the provisioning profile on developer.apple.com, I found that the profile still exists on your computer locally (not sure if it is eventually synced or if there is a way to force sync).

If you only remove the profile locally you may be okay for a while, but deleting and re-adding your Apple ID will cause the profile to reappear on your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

The accounts tab shows *both* Apple IDs and Repositories (as well as "servers"). Make sure you have added your Apple ID by clicking the + icon at the bottom left.

Comment: Your note about adding your Apple ID got me past the hurdle I had - thanks!  I can't select this as an answer though because it doesn't address access to provisioning profiles.

Answer (score 0):

In the accounts tab in Xcode preferences, select the account you want (appleID not repository) and click the view details button at the bottom right corner. There you will see both your certificates (at the top section) and the provisioning profiles for that account (at the bottom section).

Comment: This was certainly a key part of answering the question (thanks!), but I couldn't reach this step initially.   It wasn't until I saw the answer from Bo A that I was able to see my Apple ID listed.  I also wanted to be able to delete a provisioning profile (which is what set me on this path initially).  I appreciate your response!

Comment: You can delete the provisioning profile from Apple Dev Portal and it Xcode will get the changes the next time you open it.

Comment: I tried this before and just repeated the experiment now.  Deleted a profile from the portal and then closed and re-opened Xcode (did this a couple times in a row).  The provisioning profile deleted from portal still exists locally.  I'm using Xcode Version 6.1 (6A1052d).